# Using sub() in R to isolate numbers in a sequence

Tags: r, gsub

I have a sequence of numbers in R that is read as a **character**:

```
seq <- "[21.72851586341858, 21.928125858306885, 22.12797784805298, 22.328081846237183, 22.478025913238525, 22.678025007247925, 22.82824683189392, 23.02808690071106, 23.178125858306885, 23.37819004058838]"
```

I am trying to use sub() to isolate each individual number. I would like to turn this character sequence into a **numerical** sequence, e.g.:

```
print(seq)
[1] 21.72851586341858 21.928125858306885 22.12797784805298 22.328081846237183 22.478025913238525 22.678025007247925 22.82824683189392 23.02808690071106 23.178125858306885 23.37819004058838
```

In this case, the input would be the character string and the output would be a numeric vector of length 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `base R` option is to use `greexpr/regmatches`

```
as.numeric(regmatches(seq, gregexpr("[0-9.]+", seq))[[1]])
```

---

But, this can also be done easily with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract_all(seq, "[0-9.]+")[[1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the first character (and maybe the last one, too) from the string and then split it using `strsplit` with `,` as delimiter and then save it `as.numeric`. Writing it all in one line it is

```
nums <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(substring(seq, 2), split = ",|\\]")))
```

I only removed the first character and removed the last one using the `split =` expression.